# Harvard Business Review Typefaces

Tags: typography, typefaces

I am wondering if there are any references to the typefaces used by the Harvard Business Review in their monthly publication. Does anyone have some useful pointers?

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is this question related to TeX?

Comment: OK, Thank you. Do you have any suggestions as to where I can post this question?  Is there another Stack where I can post the more general typesetting questions that may not be _directly_ related to TeX?

Answer (score 0):

Did you think to try Google? On the first page of links was this- 
http://www.commarts.com/columns/james-vries

From the article - 
"New typeface families were brought in: Guardian and Brunel from Commercial Type and National from Kris Sowersby."